# Como atualizar uma tabela com uma array no laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

CÓDIGO CONTROLLER

```
    $form_data =  array(

                   'numdoc' => $request->numdoc,
                   'data_emissao' => $date_emissao,
                   'data_debito' =>  $date_debito,
                   'cliente_id' => $request->cliente_id,
                   'devedor_id' => $request->devedor_id,
                   'valor' => $request->valor,
                   'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'meses_atraso'  => $request->meses_atraso,
                    'multa' => $request->multa,
                    'valor_recebido'  => $request->valor_recebido,

    );


Divida::update($form_data);
```

> Erro: Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() should not be called statically

Comment: Qual é o campo chave da tabela?

Comment: Na tabela está como id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconselho a estudar um pouco a documentação do Eloquent do Laravel.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Para criar um registro utilize o método create();

```
$form_data =  array(

                   'numdoc' => $request->numdoc,
                   'data_emissao' => $date_emissao,
                   'data_debito' =>  $date_debito,
                   'cliente_id' => $request->cliente_id,
                   'devedor_id' => $request->devedor_id,
                   'valor' => $request->valor,
                   'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'meses_atraso'  => $request->meses_atraso,
                    'multa' => $request->multa,
                    'valor_recebido'  => $request->valor_recebido,

    );


Divida::create($form_data);
```

Pode utilizar o update se já tiver uma instância do modelo por ex.

```
  //Pesquisa de devolve o Model com o Id = 1 e atualiza o campo valor_recebido

  Divida::find(1)->update(['valor_recebido' => $request->valor_recebido]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria utilizar associação em massa do laravel. Dessa forma não é necessário "setar" todos os campos um por um.

```
// Pega todos os campos da request
$formData = $request->all();  

// Adiciona o campo user_id
$formData['user_id'] Auth::id();

// Criar
Divida::create($formData);

// Atualizar
$divida = Divida::find(1);
$divida->fill($formData)->save();
```